# How to hide the address bar on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, canvas, hide, address-bar

I am building a game with cocos creator.
The game works on mobile browsers.

I what users to swipe the screen and get it to work on full screen.

There are lot of information available on the web, but I can't seems to get it working for my game.

General idea seems to be to increase the height of div containing the canvas more and call

```
 document.getElementById("GameDiv").style.height = '120%';
  setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 50 );
```

For some reason this is not working for me.

I must have missed a important step?
Can someone point what I am doing wrong?

```css
html {
  -ms-touch-action: none;
}

body, canvas, div {
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* Remove spin of input type number */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;

  cursor: default;
  color: #888;
  background-color: #333;

  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#Cocos2dGameContainer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
}

canvas {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

a:link, a:visited {
  color: #666;
}

a:active, a:hover {
  color: #666;
}

p.header {
  font-size: small;
}

p.footer {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.progress-bar {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 80%;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    /*margin: 0 -175px;         */
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;           
}

.progress-bar span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
    transition: width .4s ease-in-out; 
    background-color: #34c2e3;    
}

.stripes span {
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);            
    
    animation: animate-stripes 1s linear infinite;             
}

@keyframes animate-stripes {
    0% {background-position: 0 0;} 100% {background-position: 60px 0;}
}

#GameDiv, #Cocos3dGameContainer, #GameCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Cocos Creator | NewProject</title>

  <!--http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/-->
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>

  <!--https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html-->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

  <!-- force webkit on 360 -->
  <meta name="renderer" content="webkit"/>
  <meta name="force-rendering" content="webkit"/>
  <!-- force edge on IE -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <!-- force full screen on some browser -->
  <meta name="full-screen" content="yes"/>
  <meta name="x5-fullscreen" content="true"/>
  <meta name="360-fullscreen" content="true"/>


  <!--fix fireball/issues/3568 -->
  <!--<meta name="browsermode" content="application">-->
  <meta name="x5-page-mode" content="app">

  <!--<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href=".png" />-->
  <!--<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href=".png" />-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="GameDiv">
      <div id="Cocos3dGameContainer">
        <canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  
<!-- Polyfills bundle. -->
<script src="src/polyfills.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>

<!-- SystemJS support. -->
<script src="src/system.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>

<!-- Import map -->
<script src="src/import-map.json" type="systemjs-importmap" charset="utf-8"> </script>

<script>
    System.import('./index.js').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); })
</script>

<script>




  function hideAddressBar() {
    console.log("hide address called");
    document.getElementById("GameDiv").style.height = '120%';
      setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 50 );

  }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The idea of increasing elements to hide the addressbar is not a working solution, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

Comment: @Teemu I have seen this implement. But I am not exactly sure how it was done

Comment: As simple as [that](https://jsfiddle.net/vuhw0qa5/).

Comment: @Teemu thank you for your answer. Seems to work on most of the browsers. But does not seems to work on Safari. Any workaround for that?

Comment: Yeah, throw that device out of window, it's just an expensive toy ... Posts found from the [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dfullscreen+in+safari) are not promising either.

Comment: @Teemu the reason I am trying to do is, I have seen it working on iPhone. What I understand is height of the div increased more than the screen then call scroll to top. For some reason I must be missing a important step since it is not working

Comment: This game shows it is possible to go to full screen or at least hide the address bar. https://www.google.com/logos/2016/scoville/scoville16.html?hl=en